# Suggestions regarding a string hashing function which ignores ordering of characters

Tags: c++, string, hash, unordered-map

I need a hashing function for `unordered_map<string, int>` in c++. I need the keys to be hashed based on the contents, but it should not depend upon the order of contents.

For example, in my map, the keys are string, and I need "ac", "ca" to generate the same hash value, but "bb" should generate a different hash value.

I tried summing up the contents of the string, but I realized that in that case, "ac" and "bb" generate the same hash value.

There is similar question [Does a string hash exist which can ignore the order of chars in this string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545698/does-a-string-hash-exist-which-can-ignore-the-order-of-chars-in-this-string) , but that has not been answered either.

Comment: Sort the strings before hashing them.  That means you hash `ac` for both `ac` and `ca`, so they hash to the same value as required, but `bb` (presumably) hashes to a different value.

Comment: ^ he meant to say "sort the characters within the string".

Comment: Yes. Sorting them worked for now. But It would be great if there is a linear time hashing function without any extra memory for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a * b * c is equivalent to a * c * b, you can multiply together the characters instead of adding them.

This should also be a lot faster than having to sort all the characters within each string before hashing them.

Comment: I think this will not work in all the cases. For example, If ascii values started from 0, then cc => 9 also l => 9 . Although this may not be the case,  but collisions can occur I guess. It would be nice If I can somehow avoid collisions. I'm saying this because I know that string length is limited to 50 or so in my requirements. Sorry for not adding this info to the question.

Comment: @Anoop: collisions can occur with any hashing function; that's the point of them.  The concept suggested in the answer is almost certainly that you use the raw ASCII values (so `a` => 97, `b` => 98, `c` => 99, etc), but you can still run into problems with distinct strings ending up producing the same product.  If the strings are any decent length, you'll end up doing the computation modulus some number, possibly a power of 2 such as 2^32 or 2^64, but that doesn't alter the collisions.

Comment: You cannot ***avoid*** collisions, since you are summarizing hundreds of bits down to only 32 or only 64 bits.  By definition, this will cause collisions.  Luckily, a hash function does not have to guarantee lack of collisions, it only needs to make sure they happen rarely.  ASCII values of letters start at 65 for uppercase 'A', 97 for lowercase 'a', so by multiplying these kinds of numbers together you are highly unlikely to run into collisions, except for the particular kind of collisions that you want to see happening.  (Same characters out of order.)